# PyCharm projects with underscore

Tags: pycharm

(I am a beginner at Python and PyCharm).

PyCharm 2020.1.3 (Community Edition) / macOS Catalina / Python 3.8

In the directory `foo`, I have a project `foo` with a single file `the_example.py` containing `print("this is foo")`. Executing the project works fine with the expected output appearing.

I refactor the project name to `foo_fum`; all is still okay.

I refactor the directory name to `foo_fum` and I get the error `Invalid Python interpreter selected for the project`.

Starting a new project from scratch with a directory name containing an underscore has the same results.

Why? What am I not understanding?

Comment: What interpreter is specified in `File - Settings - Project - Project Interpreter`?

Comment: I believe you are speaking of the following on a Mac: PyCharm > Preferences > Project Interpreter (for current project) which specifies "Python 3.8 (foo) (~/Desktop/foo/venv/bin/python)".

Comment: Seems it's path should be changed to `~/Desktop/foo_fum/venv/bin/python` via `Show All - Edit` or it could be just re-added with a new path